# PYTHON How to make an exceptional case for decimal numbers and negative number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

User input a value and I want it to be ONLY **positive integer**. When the entered value is not positive integer it will loop and ask the user to enter again. How do I write the exceptional case for it? I want to write a exceptional case for negative number, decimal number and string.

Comment: No different than ensuring the user doesn't enter something that's not an integer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a looping example:

```
>>> x = -1
>>> while(x < 0):
...   x = input('Enter a positive integer> ')
...   try:
...     x = int(x)
...   except ValueError:
...     x = -1
...
Enter a positive integer> aaa
Enter a positive integer> -123
Enter a positive integer> 5.2
Enter a positive integer> 5
>>> print(x)
5
```

The decimal fails because it's equivalent to `int("5.2")` which generates a ValueError

Answer (score 1):

how about using a regular expression

```
import re

re.match('^[1-9][0-9]*$', input)
```

---

```
def isPositive(input):
     return bool(re.match('^[1-9][0-9]*$', input))


In [26]: isPositive('3')
Out[26]: True

In [27]: isPositive('-4')
Out[27]: False

In [28]: isPositive('0')
Out[28]: False

In [29]: isPositive('345')
Out[29]: True

In [30]: isPositive('3.5')
Out[30]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a simple check:

```
n = int(input())
while n < 0:  # simply check that it's not negative:
    print("can't be negative!")
    n = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted float to int because I was trying Fibonacci sequence

```
test = True
user1 = ''

while test:
    user1 = float(input("Enter numbers of fibonacci : "))
    if int(user1) == user1:

        if user1 > 0:
            user1 = int(user1)
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a positive integer")

    else:
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
```